# Regex Negative lookahead not work as expected

Tags: c#, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a following text:

```
 #arkLogo {
            background-image: url("static/images/arklogo.png");
        }
```

And i've create a regex to extract all urls, like

```
static/images/arklogo.png
```

My regex is:

```
(?!url\s*\()("|').*(?=("|')\))
```

But it matches url with first quote like this:

```
"static/images/arklogo.png
```

I try to move scope of lookahead to capture this quote like this

```
(?!url\s*\(("|')).*(?=("|')\))
```

But in this case it mathes entire line

```
background-image: url("static/images/arklogo.png");
```

**I found a solution,** i just need to use positive lookbehind, like this:

```
(?<=url\s*\(("|')).*(?=("|')\))
```

Comment: Feel free to add an answer to your own question rather than editing the solution in. It's an accepted practice here at SO, even if it feels a bit like taking "selfies." Others may chime in as well with caveats or better methods.

Comment: And being up-voted for an answer gives **double** the points!

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, i just need to use positive lookbehind, like this:

```
(?<=url\s*\(("|')).*(?=("|')\))
```